# How to get json data from the next Ajax Request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to alert the json data, Right now it does not work

Probably missing user_info but I do not know where to add it

*By the way, the user & password mentioned in the request is free, so there is no sensitive information.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgjefjmd/215/

JSON OUTPUT:

```
{"user_info":{"username":"Tara","password":"Tara","message":"","auth":1,"status":"Active",...
```

-

```
<button id="jsonp2" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Send JSONP Request</button>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jsonp2").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://linux-app.tv:8080/player_api.php?username=azmir&password=azmir&type=m3u",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "user_info",
        success: function(data) {
          alert("Username:" + data.username + "\npassword:" + data.password + "\nstatus:" + data.status);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  function user_info(data){
    alert("Username:" + data.username + "\npassword:" + data.password + "\nstatus:" + data.status);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

First the response of the webservice you are calling is not a valid `jsonp` response, basically it's just json.

So when you are also implementing the backend, then I would recommend to change the response to jsonp - something like:

```
my_callback({"username":"Tara","password":"Tara"});
```

If the service just returns a json (like I see in the jsfiddle example atm.) just remove the `jsonp` and `dataType` attribute to only fetch json. In addition there was just some small issue in your callback, on how you read the response - Please look into the updated JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lgjefjmd/218/